# Editing email validation for Firebase Authentication (Flutter)

Tags: firebase-authentication, email-validation

Good day,

I would like to know if anyone has knowledge where we can edit the email validation for Firebase (Firestore Auth) in the firebase console. The reason for this is, I had work with company that have a custom email handler. Their email is just @(their company name) without .com and firebase checks the last part.

Im working with a (tutorial) app project and would like to accept these custom emails during sign up.

If anyone has any idea how this can be done, that would greatly help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify the email validation that Firebase performs in its console and on its servers.

If the console doesn't accept a valid email address, consider adding it through the API.

Also, please [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to let the team know about the issues.

Comment: Ahh thats unfortunate theb. Well ill try the link and send a commwnt, maybe they can listen to my dillema. Thank you